# How to tell Vim to extend the background color to the whole screen?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, color

I have an issue with the Vim color schemes: The background color does not fill the whole screen. For example, in the "blue" color scheme the whole screen should turn blue. Instead, the blue background only extends to the end of each line. Is this a setting in the console I'm missing or is this an issue with my vim default settings?

I'm only having this issue with Ubuntu 10.10. `echo $TERM` outputs `xterm-color`.

[Update]: To eliminate error sources my minimal ~/.vimrc looks like this:

```
filetype plugin on
colorscheme blue
syntax on
```

`/etc/vim/vimrc` contains the unchanged defaults of Ubuntu

Comment: are you using screen?

Comment: No, I'm not using screen

Comment: have you tried setting in vim `set t_Co=256`?

Comment: can you post the relevant section of .vimrc?

Comment: `set t_Co=256` makes the foreground text blink, but does not change the background color.

Answer (score 18):

[As explained here](http://snk.tuxfamily.org/log/vim-256color-bce.html), disable **Background Color Erase** (BCE) by clearing the `t_ut` terminal option (run `:set t_ut=` in Vim and then press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to refresh the terminal's display) so that Vim extends the color scheme's background color to the whole terminal screen.  This also works if Vim is being used inside tmux or GNU screen.

Comment: Do you know why this kind of "arcana" is necessary? `screen` has existed for at least a decade, so has Vim. This isn't specific to the Zenburn color scheme in Vim -- I am using One and the linked advice fixes the same issue on my end. My `TERM` inside `screen` is set to `screen.xterm-256color` (I have not configured anything, it's what I get after installing and running `screen`). Why isn't Vim able to properly detect how it should talk to the terminal emulator, on its own?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 12.04 and OpenBSD 5.1 when using vim inside of tmux. Ultimately, I was able to resolve it by setting my terminal type to *screen-256color*.